# R tidyverse delete rows that have identical values in dynamic number of columns

Tags: r, duplicates, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = data.frame(x = c("1_1_1", "2_1_1", "3_1_1"),
                y = c("1_1_1", "1_1_1", "1_1_1"),
                z = c("1_1_1", "4_1_1", "1_1_1"))
```

I now want to dynamically go through all my columns and check if any **two** columns have the same values **per row**. So I want to compare x with y, x with z and y with z. Please note that I have much more columns in reality.

The desired outcome is to remove every row where there is at least one duplicated value, i.e. in my example I want to remove row 1 (because all values are identical) and row 3 (because y and z are identical).

Maybe another note: in reality my data frame has ~30m rows.

I know that there's the `duplicated` or `anyDuplicated` function, but AFAIK these assume that I check for duplicates in all columns at the same time whereas I want to have it based on pair-wise column comparisons.

**EDIT**: somewhat related to this problem (and not sure if that might make things easier): I create the df `df` in a way where I have a character variable like `x=c("1_1_1", "2_1_1", "3_1_1", "1_2_1")` and so on and then I use the `expand.grid` function:

```
df = expand.grid(x, x, x)
```

which results in the duplicates in the first place. So ideally, I would create the `df` data frame in a way that prevents these duplicates right from the beginning?

Comment: I don't understand why pairwise comparison would needed when you want to check duplicates in entire row. In which case would `df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(x))), ]` fail ?

Comment: Your last edit changes your question completely. Your actual problem is that you are confusing permutations and combinations... A perfect example of A/B problem resulting in question title not matching answers at all. Please edit...

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. This works. Pairwise comparisons was just a guess from me. Not sure what the `any(duplicated())` part does under the hood, but it gives the correct results.

Comment: @antoine-sac I agree that that I had two questions (one added after my edit), but that doesn't make my initial questions invalid. Ronak Shah provided a solution to it. I also agree that the problem wouldn't occur if I had created my df differntly from the beginning (see my post). However, you are not entirely right that this is based on a confusion of combination and permutation, because the order matters in my case (so combination would be wrong), i.e., "1_1_1 // 2_1_1 // 3_1_1" in my case is different than "2_1_1 // 1_1_1 // 3_1_1".

Comment: @deschen okay..I added that too in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the first issue where you create duplicates using `expand.grid`, we can use `combn` instead which will give us combinations without duplicates

```
combn(x, 3, simplify = FALSE)

#[[1]]
#[1] "1_1_1" "2_1_1" "3_1_1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1_1_1" "2_1_1" "1_2_1"

#[[3]]
#[1] "1_1_1" "3_1_1" "1_2_1"

#[[4]]
#[1] "2_1_1" "3_1_1" "1_2_1"
```

Now what we need is to create rows with various permutations of this combination. We can manually write a function to create this permutations or use from one of the packages. Here I am using `combinat::permn`.

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, combn(x, 3, simplify = FALSE, FUN = function(y) 
        do.call(rbind, combinat::permn(y))))

#      V1    V2    V3
#1  1_1_1 2_1_1 3_1_1
#2  1_1_1 3_1_1 2_1_1
#3  3_1_1 1_1_1 2_1_1
#4  3_1_1 2_1_1 1_1_1
#5  2_1_1 3_1_1 1_1_1
#6  2_1_1 1_1_1 3_1_1
#....
```

---

To remove `duplicated` rows we can do

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(x))), ]
```